# Rounding values in a numpy array resulting from matrix calculation

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, rounding

I have some calculation involving two matrices both represented in `numpy` arrays.

After the calculation, i obtain a vector of `floats` represented in another `numpy` array.

I want to round up/down the values in this resultant vector, e.g. if the calculation gives:

```
array([1.33333, 2.56, 9.99999, 16.0])
```

then it should be rounded to:

```
array([1, 3, 10, 16])
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NumPy arrays have a [round](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy-around) method:

```
In [73]: x = np.array([1.33333, 2.56, 9.99999, 16.0])

In [74]: x.round()
Out[76]: array([  1.,   3.,  10.,  16.])
```

Comment: does this method depend on the type of floats in the array? e.g. `float32` vs. `float64`?

Comment: If `x` is of dtype `float32`, then `x.round()` will also be of dtype `float32`. And similarly for `float64`. The `round` method is not implemented for some dtypes, for example, string dtypes.